# Как правильно обойти strict_aliasing при касте похожих типов?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++17, clang, strict-aliasing

У меня есть 2 структуры, A и B, содержащие по 2 поля. При этом B отличается от A только первым полем, которое является enum class типом, унаследованным от типа первого поля A. Я хочу заполнить массив структур B через указатель на массив A. Является ли такая операция нарушением strict_aliasing, и позволяет ли std::launder устранить ub?

Минимальный воспроизводимый пример того, что я имею ввиду.

```
  #include <iostream>
    
    struct A {
        uint32_t field1{0};
        uint32_t field2{0};
    };
    
    enum class TestE : uint32_t {
    };
    
    struct B {
        TestE field1{0};
        uint32_t field2{0};
    };
    
    void test_func(A *aArr, size_t size) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            aArr[i].field1 = std::rand() % 1024;
            aArr[i].field2 = std::rand() % 1024;
        }
    }
    
    int main() {
        B arr[10];
        test_func(reinterpret_cast<A *>(arr), 10); // правильно так?
        // test_func(std::launder(reinterpret_cast<A *>(arr)), 10); // или так ?
    
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Никто вам не поможет. В итоге вы хотите через указатель типа A* менять структуру типа B. Это запрещено вне зависимости от того что вы делали с указателем.

Comment: В любом случае strict aliasing-а тут нет. Это явление (его природа лежит в области оптимизации) возникает, когда 2 (или более) указателей  разного типа адресуют одну и ту же переменную (область памяти). На практике проще всего бороться с ним можно, разделяя исходники по разным файлам и компилируя "сомнительный код" с ключем `-fno-strict-aliasing`

Comment: `Я хочу заполнить массив структур B через указатель на массив A. Является ли такая операция нарушением strict_aliasing?` Да. `позволяет ли std::launder устранить ub?` Нет.

Comment: @apv, `arr`, `aArr` - две переменные разного типа, указывающие на одну область памяти. И не важно, что одна из них массив, другая - указатель.

Comment: @avp Не следует путать просто явление aliasing и ограничения strict aliasing.

Comment: @maestro, и что вы хотели этим сказать? Надеюсь, вас же не удивляет, что `memset()` успешно прописывает память независимо от типа передаваемого ей указателя

Comment: @user7860670, хотите сказать что в этой программе есть нарушение strict aliasing?

Comment: @apv, `memset` к данному вопросу отношения не имеет, так как эта функция принимает указатель типа `void*`. Такой указатель нельзя разыменовать, а значит, и произвести с ним действия, ведущие к нарушению string aliasing. Но его можно преобразовать в указатель любого другого типа. Существует только два типа указателей, с через которые можно обратиться к памяти любого типа без нарушения strict aliasing: `char*`, `unsigned char*`. Функция `memset` внутри выполняет приведение к одному из этих типов, так как стандартная библиотека априори не содержит UB.

Comment: Здесь же имеется структура типа `B`,  к которой обращаются через указатель типа `A*`. Типы `A` и `B` никак не связаны. Значит, правило strict aliasing нарушено.

Comment: @maestro, у меня просто остатки волос встают дыбом от такой схоластики (и очевидного непонимания того, как работает транслятор и далее аппаратура)

Comment: Так легально ли это действие @avp

Comment: @avp, тогда приведите свою версию.

Comment: @DenverToha, в данном случае, да.

Comment: `Так легально ли это действие` [Нет](https://godbolt.org/z/dzqExxsxK): `dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules`.